How to add a user to MinIO server using CLI?
I have MinIO server running in docker. I need to add a user from command line
mc admin user add local ACCESSKEY SECRETKEY
mc: <ERROR> Unable to add new user. Access Denied.

why? How to add an user?
I expecting a new user with following credentials ACCESSKEY SECRETKEY
